# open unknown file name in known directory

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a special directory which only ever contains one file.

the file may vary in name and or extention type but its location is always the same directory.

based upon this information how can I launch (trigger) the file

I'm using VB.net

Comment: Do you want to load the contents into your program, or do you want it to be as if the user double-clicked the file in Windows? Do you at least know what kind of file it will be?

Comment: Yess as if the user double clicked it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Directory.GetFiles()` or `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` methods will help you find the file that is in the directory.

Assuming you're trying to execute the file, `Process.Start()` is probably what you're looking for.

If you run into any problems with either of them, you'll need to provide more details as to your situation and what you're trying to do.

Comment: eer yeah i figured but im not that good with vb.net and i could only come up with         Dim somthing As String

        somthing = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test")

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` returns an array, so the file name will be the first member of that array, so: `Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test") ... If files.Length > 0 Then ... Dim theFile As String = files(0) ... End If`